# Error when creating a dynamodb document client aws serverless using aws-xray-sdk,

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, aws-xray

I am creating a function which is supposed to write to a dynamodb and I want to generate the trace using aws-xray-sdk.

My function is

```
    private readonly docClient: DocumentClient = AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

    async createTodo(todoItem: TodoItem): Promise<TodoItem> {
        await this.docClient.put({
            TableName: this.todosTable,
            Item: todoItem
        }).promise()

        return todoItem
    }
```

This works very well when I use just the document client from aws sdk as above but because I need the trace when I pass the aws-sdk through the aws-xray-sdk  and wants to use the sdk it throws an error.
This is how I constuct it.

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk'
import * as AWSXRay from 'aws-xray-sdk'

const XAWS = AWSXRay.captureAWS(AWS)
```

then when I do

`private readonly docClient: DocumentClient = XAWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()`
I get the error

```
      TS2339: Property 'DocumentClient' does not exist on type 
'PatchedAWSClientConstructor<ClientConfiguration, typeof DynamoDB>'.
```

How can I do to eliminate this error or possibly get a document client that can be used for the trace with aws-xray.

Dependencies.
    "aws-xray-sdk": "^2.2.0",
   "aws-sdk": "^2.433.0",

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with the type definitions; it all looks like a mess to me.  I recommend defeating the compiler by bringing in X-Ray with `const AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk');`, instead of `import * as`.

Answer (score 5):

Using `const AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk')` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Please use

```js
import AWSXRay from "aws-xray-sdk-core";
```

This was explained on a similar issue on the AWS X-Ray JS SDK repo: https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/issues/491